# Issue with getting the derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the derivative of the following integral:

$\int_{\cos(x)}^{1} \sqrt{1-t^2} dt$

My steps are:

$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_{\cos(x)}^{1} \sqrt{1-t^2} dt \right) = -\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_{1}^{\cos(x)} \sqrt{1-t^2} dt \right) = -\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)} \frac{d}{dx}\left( \cos(x) \right) = -\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)} \cdot -\sin(x) = \sin^2(x) $

However, the book says the right answer is $ \lvert \sin(x) \rvert \sin(x) $

What am I missing here?

Comment: Unrelated: you should use `\cos` and `\sin` to get the proper font and spacing: $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing that $\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}=\vert \sin x \vert$. In general $\sqrt{a^2}$ is equal to $\vert a \vert$ and not to $a$. In particular for $a \lt 0$. **The square root is a non negative number.**